# Loop list items in JSON

Tags: python, json, spotify

I am able to make a successful query to Spotify searching for an artist. My issue is I want to pull the artist's image URL from the JSON response.

Every time I try to get the URL I get the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
import pyCiscoSpark
import json
import sys

def _url(path):
    return 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search' + path

artist = 'AC/DC'

spotifyR = requests.get(_url('?q={:s}&type=artist'.format(artist)))
spotifyJson = spotifyR.json()
req = spotifyJson['artists']['items']['images']['url']
print(req)
```

I want the URL of the images in a dict so I can pick the correct size of image that Spotify has.

Comment: Evidently at least one level of the JSON response is an array (which becomes a list), not an object (which becomes a dictionary), so you need to use a numerical index rather than a string key.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a visual look at the object by

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(spotifyJson)
```

Indeed as jonrsharpe pointed out, 'items' is a list, so either you iterate over it or pick one element. 
'Images' is a list also.

```
images = spotifyJson['artists']['items'][0]['images']
for img in images:
  print(img['width'])
  print(img['height'])
  print(img['url'])
```

Comment: Thank you your suggestion helped!

Answer (score 0):

The value for the key 'items' in the json response is a list of dictionaries. You might want to do something like:

```
   images = spotifyJson['artists']['items'][0]['images']
   for img in images:
       print img
```

This will print the info dictionary for all the images. Then you can process which of the urls you want from there :)